# How can I create a bump line across an object using textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, objects, node-editor

I want to create a photo realistic lego man in bender cycles.
But the problem is that I cant figure out how to use my black and white texture
to make this little bump line across the lego minifigures arm.

My scene.
[image: My lego minifigure scene]

I want the result to look like this.

[image: realistic lego minifigures arm with bump across its arm]

It's driving me crazy!!!
Please Help.

Comment: I think the piece you are missing might be UV Unwrapping. In edit mode select the vertices of the arm and position the uv's in the image editor so that your bump line is positioned where you want it on the arm.

Comment: I already unwrap it with project from view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following...

1. Add a Bump Node
2. Add invert node to your bump map texture.
3. Plug it into the height input on the Bump node.
4. Plug the bump node into the Normals channel of your shaders.
5. Adjust the strength value on the Bump node, to match your need.

**Note** bump is exaggerated for demostration purposes.

[image]

Here is the blend file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But now I need my other texture to go over the bump

Comment: You can add your texture map on the diffuse channel.